# How to split a long string into two

Tags: split, robotframework

Example:

```
Log To Console   This is a very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long string
```

The string above is very long so it doesn't fit into 1 line so I want to split it into 2 (or more) parts and put every part in a separate line. Like this (in C++):

```
cout << "This is a very very very very very very very very very very very very"
        " very very very very very very very very very very long string" << endl;
```

Comment: did you try to consult doc?
http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#dividing-test-data-to-several-rows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [Catenate](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Catenate) keyword and the ellipsis (...) for line continuation, :

```
${long var}=    Catenate     This is a very very very very very very very very very very very very
                   ...       very very very very very very very very very very long string
Log To Console  My long variable is: ${long var}
```

By default it catenates the arguments with spaces, which is changeable with the `SEPARATOR` argument (it must be the 1st passed to the keyword).

Answer (score 3):

Using Evaluate might also work:

```
${varA} =    Set Variable    Head of the string -
${varB} =    Set Variable    which is just too long
${result} =     Evaluate    ${varA}${varB}
```

Comment: Good alternative; you can combine these, and use only one variable - first `${varA} =    Set Variable    Head of the string -`, and then just pass it in a second Set Variable - `${varA} =    Set Variable    ${varA} which is just too long`. This also drops the need for Evaluate